# React stopped working normally during update

Tags: reactjs

When switching from "react": "^ 16.2.0", "react-dom": "^ 16.2.0" to 17.0.1, all hooks stopped working, and when they clicked on the application links, they began to refresh the page, instead of a quick transition, what could be the problem?

Comment: also does not fire onClick when clicking on a button, it used to work

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean since React v16.2 didn't have hooks, they didn't exist yet. Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code with issue. If you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) it'd be a trivial matter to switch between these two React versions to test it.

Comment: with the command "npm ls react" shows version 16.14.0 and hooks work on this version in the whole project, in package json shows 16.2.0

Comment: Ok, React hooks didn't change between React 16 and 17 versions. You also mention that "clicking" links has undesired behavior. React 17 ***did*** change how the event system works. See [Changes to Event Delegation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#changes-to-event-delegation) and [how to resolve common issues](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#fixing-potential-issues). In fact, you should read most of that blog and refamiliarize with the React ecosystem. If you could share a tangible code example and error you have we can further help.

Answer (score 0):

this page might help you migrate from react 16 to 17. [React 17](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html)

this problem can also be because of the migration while working. I think react-script doesn't work well while migrating. so trying a restart might help as well.

check the log and if you find something. please share it with us so we can understand better.